# Get current state (open, closed) with mootools 1.12 Fx.Slide

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm using this Fx.Slide script in my site:

```
        var togglers = $$('.toggler'), expanders = $$('.expandable');
    togglers.each(function(toggler, index){            
        var fx = new Fx.Slide(expanders[index]).hide();
        toggler.addEvents({
            click: function(e){
                e = new Event(e);
                fx.toggle();
                e.stop();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Which is working just fine. What I wasn't able to do is get the current state of the slide so I can assign some open/closed icons on the toggler element.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the attribue open of the slider:

```
if(fx.open){
   //whatever you need to do
}else{
   //whatever you need to do
}
```

i think you need put the slider in an array to be able to access them later...

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could even store the `Fx.Slide`s in the togglers themselves, if you don't want to keep a separate array.

```
[...]
togglers.each(function(toggler, index){            
    var fx = new Fx.Slide(expanders[index]).hide();
    expanders[index].store('slide',fx)
    toggler.addEvents({
        [...]
    });
});
```

Then later you can check the status, like mklfarha said:

```
if(expanders[index].retrieve('slide').open){
    //do some stuff
}
```